# The way to filter query based on intersection between 2 many-to-many relationships

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Is there a way to run .filter() method in sqlalchemy orm to determine if any item from one list (as many to many relationship) is in another list (also many to many)?

For example I have following models and relationship between them:
User model (with followed_countries field that is many to many relationship with Country model)
Country model
Article model (with country_tags field that is many to many relationship with Country model)

My question is “Is there a way to select articles which have any of country in country_tags that user follows in followed_countries? (basically intersection between 2 lists)”

Code fragment if needed:

```
country_follower_relation = db.Table(
        'country_follower',
        db.Column('user_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'),
                primary_key=True),
        db.Column('country_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('country.id'),
                primary_key=True))


    country_articletags_relation = db.Table(
        'country_tag',
        db.Column('article_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('article.id'),
                primary_key=True),
        db.Column('country_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('country.id'),
                primary_key=True))


    class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
        id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
        username = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, unique=True)

        followed_countries = db.relationship(
            'Country', secondary=country_follower_relation, lazy=True,
            backref='followers')


    class Country(db.Model):
        id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
        name = db.Column(db.String(60), index=True, unique=True)


    class Article(db.Model):
        id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
        body = db.Column(db.Text(100000), nullable=False)
        title = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=False)

        country_tags = db.relationship(
            'Article', secondary=country_articletags_relation, lazy='dynamic',
            backref='articles', cascade='all')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this method](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/postgresql.html#sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.ARRAY.Comparator.overlap). Example:

```
articles = session.query(Article).filter(Article.country_tags.overlap(user.followed_countries)).all()
```